# What does this Chinese symbol mean?

Tags: translation, simplified-characters

I am tired of searching and not finding any result. Please help me translate this symbol.

[image: Chinese symbol]

Comment: Can you provide a photo or at least some context?

Comment: Close vote - Questions  are off-topic unless prior research effort is clearly indicated

Answer (score 4):

That might be a rendering of 忠 zhong1, meaning ‘faithful, loyal, honest’.  This character consists of two parts, the radical 心 ‘heart’ and a phonetic element 中.  It seems that the writer has allowed the radical to snake up over the top in an unorthodox way.  That’s my guess anyway.

Comment: Good call. I was gonna say 史+J

Answer (score 3):

This means faithful of course. However the meaning one wants to express by writing this on his body (I bet you see this in tattoos) means "I'm a tough guy and I'm in a gang".

That's because loyalty has been regarded to be the most important virtue of gangsters. So a troop wrote this symbol on the body is a good one.

Comment: That didn't occur to me - hopefully the OP will fill us in about context!

Comment: @user2619 LOL, yes, sometime it means gangster style!

Answer (score 1):

It most resembles zhōng (see image below) however, a better rendering or a picture of the typed character is needed to be sure.

[image: zhong]

Answer (score 1):

It means loyalty. And we often relate 忠 to 关二爷(Guan Yu), so you can see 忠 in many tattoos.

One of the famous tattoos is perhaps Allen Iverson's.

[image]